# Flutter not producing a screen

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development, flutter-design

Thanks for giving time to read this question and help me.

I have a SideDrawer in my home screen having two options. If I click on 'Tickets' I want Flutter to produce a new page with the tickets.
But, this doesn't seem to be the case. Whenever i tap on 'Tickets', nothing loads. I am pretty sure the function userData() does execute, but doesn't load the new page.

Comment: Show your `userData()` function. As this is working correctly. For new screen. You need to push new screen which i doubt you are pushing in userData. So show us `userData()` function.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Also call your userData function as `userData(context)`

Comment: I think you need to learn navigations. you CANNOT do `TicketList(context, value:uid)` More here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Comment: This shouldn't occur. Post your update code. PS Dont remove the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push new screen on the navigation screen. So do this

```
Future<void> userData(BuildContext context) async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user  = await auth.currentUser();
    uid = user.uid;
    goToTicketScreen(context,uid); //Add thiis
  }
```

Then define the function as follow

```
Future<void> goToTicketScreen(BuildContext context,String uid) async {
 

  await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) =>TicketList(value: uid),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: @ripcord Show what you updated. And post it

Comment: Dont do this `TicketList(BuildContext context, {this.value});`  just keep it the same like  `TicketList({this.value});`

Comment: @ripcord yes. It might be the case. You can insert assertion there like `assert(document!=null)` and see what happend